# Text wrap working in firefox but not in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, styles, stylesheet

Hi I want to wrap a link text. I tried using following css class.

```
.abc{
    width: 185px;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

It works fine in firefox, but its not working for IE9 and IE8.

I searched many places for solution but there they have suggested the same above css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add display:table property and remove break-all. It will work in all browser.

```
.abc{
width: 185px;
word-wrap: break-word;
display:table;
}
```